# Getting a delete button inside a table to work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I'm trying to add rows of information to a table, each with a delete button that will remove the row  when clicked. Delete button isn't showing up, and I can't figure out why. It's probably something small I'm overlooking?

```js
$(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var deleteBtn =
      "<button type='button' class='btn'>" +
      "delete" + "</button>";

    $(".btn").on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    });

    var newElement =
      "<tr>" + "<td>" + $('#title').val() +
      "</td>" + "<td>" + $('#rating').val() +
      "</td>" + "<td>" + $(deleteBtn) +
      "</td>" + "</tr>";

    $("#table1").append($(newElement));
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  background: grey;
}

th {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
}

td {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
}

#table {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.btn {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      Title:
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title"> Rating:
      <input type="text" name="rating" id="rating">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="table">
    <table id="table1">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/vltrcltr/pen/earXPE

Comment: Your code is working the button is showing. Your code above is different from the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a jQuery object (`$(deleteBtn)`) instead of the HTML string you created; instead of:

```
var newElement = 
  "<tr>" + "<td>" + $('#title').val()
  + "</td>" + "<td>" + $('#rating').val() 
  + "</td>"  + "<td>" + $(deleteBtn) 
  + "</td>" + "</tr>";
```

remove the surrounding jQuery:

```
var newElement = 
  "<tr>" + "<td>" + $('#title').val()
  + "</td>" + "<td>" + $('#rating').val() 
  + "</td>"  + "<td>" + deleteBtn
  + "</td>" + "</tr>";
```

```js
$(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var deleteBtn =
      "<button type='button' class='btn'>" +
      "delete" + "</button>";

    $(".btn").on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    });

    var newElement =
      "<tr>" + "<td>" + $('#title').val() +
      "</td>" + "<td>" + $('#rating').val() +
      "</td>" + "<td>" + deleteBtn +
      "</td>" + "</tr>";

    $("#table1").append($(newElement));
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  background: grey;
}

th {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
}

td {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
}

#table {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.btn {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      Title:
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title"> Rating:
      <input type="text" name="rating" id="rating">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="table">
    <table id="table1">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem with appending `$(deleteBtn)` to a String is that JavaScript first coerces the Object to a String, which results in the `[Object object]`.